# Setting the opacity of an element within a div with opacity defined by CSS?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm working on a project in which I am using an image as a background for a menu. I have defined classes in my CSS stylesheet that dictate the appearance when items are or are not "selected", meaning the user is not on the page each item is linked to.

I have it structured with a div on top of the image with styles applied to it to make it have a semi-transparent white background, so it looks like that part of the image is highlighted. Each semi-transparent div also contains the text that makes up the link, with a color set to white. I would like the div to keep the opacity, while the text remains at an opacity of "1".

I have tried the method discussed in a similar question ([CSS - Apply Opacity to Element but NOT To Text Within The Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175009/css-apply-opacity-to-element-but-not-to-text-within-the-element)) but the method does not seem to work for me.

I've posted the bit of code for the link on JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Cwca22/uG5y8/ if you'd like to take a look at it.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers to my problem Kolink, Nacho, techfoobar and jblasco. It's all good now, so thanks again. ;^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure CSS solution, and are willing to change your markup a little, take a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4MZ/3/

It treats each "link" as a combination of separate background and text elements, and then positions them over each other, so that only the background div uses transparency.

Comment: is it okay if I use your code in a commercial project? I have modified it a little as needed, but I just wanted to make sure it was up for use beforehand.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the background colour of the `div` to be partially transparent to show the image through, but keep the text opaque? That's simple :3

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">Text</div>
```

If you want to provide support for browsers that don't allow this format, then you need:

```
<div style="background: #ffffff; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old problem without any standard solutions yet! This is something known to be impossible with today's CSS. The only solution i know of is using JS. Using JS you can catch the mousemove of the affected H# and create/position an element. This new 'over' element should not be a child of the DIV with opacity 0.2.

Comment: Ok, I might have to try that, thanks. I'm surprised there's nothing defined yet to solve these kind of problems!

Comment: Yes, seriously. I believe this problem has been there from the time CSS2 was under design or something. Zero standard cross-browser way to achieve this till date!

Answer (score 0):

Once i wrote a jsFiddle for a problem like this. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/A53Py/5/

Create a same-level element which positions absolutely behind the elements without opacity. No need to tell it's *cross browser*.

Hope it helps